# iCloud backup from old 4S to new 4S?

Tags: icloud, iphone, restore

I just got a replacement for my 4S. Before, I did an iCloud backup and thought I could just restore from that. But with the new phone, it says there's no backup to restore from available.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backups are generally portable across any and all iOS device. Could the new device be at a lower software level? Try an over the air update to ios 5.0.1 and also be sure everything is exact in the account. xxx@mac.com is not always the same as xxx@me.com.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if that's the problem. The old device was 5.1, so I'm already downloading to upgrade.

Comment: 5.1 was the problem. Since it's only Apps, Contacts etc. I thought it would work with 5.0.1 as well.

Comment: Sometimes it works at odd versions, other times you get an intentional blank - other times even worse - crashes. Glad it was just an "update all".